# How to get the current pathname correctly in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using a library called [Material-UI](https://mui.com), to build up my app layout. I am using its `<ListItemButton>` component inside the sidenav of my app. Now. this component `<ListItemButton>` is not a link, its a button. but it has some styles, you can see how it looks [here, click me](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/#basic-list). This component accepts a `component` prop, what this `component` prop does is that it basically allows you to render something inside of it, for instance, I can give it `<div/>`, I can give it `<a/>` I can give it`<b/>` etc etc, but I can also give it a React component. and that's what I am doing here. I am giving it the React router `<NavLink>` component.

Now. this is so easy, just give it the `<NavLink>` component and its going to work. But, unfortunately, it doesn't allow you to write `<NavLink>` as `<NavLink>`, you must write it as `NavLink` without the brackets, therefore, I can not pass any arguments to it.

Luckily, the way this Material-UI works, is that when it sees a prop inside one of its components such as the `<ListItemButton>` component that it doesn't understand, it automatically passes that prop to the child component. so in our case, if we wrote a prop that is not inside the `<ListItemButton>` documentation, it's going to pass it to the `NavLink` component.

hence, we can pass the `to` prop. as follows:

```
<ListItemButton to="/users" component={NavLink}>
```

So far so good. The last thing we have to make is to make sure that the ListItemButton component is going to be highlighted whenever the link in the search bar matches the **NavLink** specified path.

The good news is that the `<ListItemButton>` has a predefined prop that makes it looks on the screen as selected, so it highlights it a bit darker. this prop is called the `selected` prop, it accepts a Boolean, (**true** or **false**). SO:

How can we do this? we can do it by comparing if the URL in the searchbar matches the path we specified in the `to` prop.

Now this was the introduction of why I **want** to find out the currently used **path**.

So here's the question:

as I know, the only way to do this is to compare if the currently visited link is the same path as the **NavLink** or **Link** component by doing something like so:

```
<ListItemButton  to="/users" component={NavLink} selected={pathname === "/users"}>
```

I know that this question was answered before, I saw the thread where people were mentioning that the way to do so is by using the `useLocation()` hook, they were saying you can do it like so: then do the comparison:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation()
```

However, this doesn't always work, for instance, if the user visited the following links, the ListItemButton component is **Not** going to be highlighted (selected):

- http://example.com/users ✅ works
- http://example.com/users/ ❌ doesn't work
- http://example.com/users// ❌ doesn't work
- http://example.com/users/// ❌ doesn't work

You might say, okay, simply compare using `.includes()` as follows:

```
<ListItemButton  to="/users" component={NavLink} selected={pathname.includes("/users")}>
```

But remember, this shouldn't be if you have other routes in the sidenav such as:

- **Manage Users** *(/users)*
- **Create User** *(/users/create)*

because if you did the comparison using the `.includes()` method, you'll end up highlighting (**select**ing) both NavLinks (ListItemButton).

Is there a built-in React Router Hook, or method that can get the route name correctly, the exact name that is defined by me in the `<BrowserRouter>` in my index.js  file?

[Full example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-resonance-ivuvpr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The `NavLink` component already handles matching/styling active routes by default. Why are you trying to manage this manually yourself? What is the use case and what is the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese, Good question, Okay. I didn't know someone is going to ask this. but, I can't apply the style prop directly to the NavLink component. because of.. I am using a library that's called https://mui.com and I am putting the NavLink component inside another component called **ListItemButton**, the way it works is like: `<ListItemButton  to={item.path} component={NavLink} selected={pathname == item.path}>` and the thing is: I can't write <NavLink> inside the `component` prop, I have to write NavLink (without the brackets) instead.

Comment: I see. Can you edit your question to include a more representative question of your *actual* use case? As-is, this has every smell of an XY problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese, okay thanks for asking this question. now I will have to edit the whole question again 

Comment: @DrewReese, yes sure. I will do that

Comment: Are you using v5 or v6 of react-router?

Comment: @Andy, v6,  the latest version.

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated my question  suggest me any edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see, you are trying to style the button and not really the `NavLink` component if I'm understanding your post correctly. I think you may be looking for the `useMatch` hook.

> Returns true if the URL for the given "to" value matches the current
> URL. This is useful for components that need to know "active" state, e.g. `<NavLink>`.

```
import { useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const isUserRoute = useMatch("/user");

...

<ListItemButton
  to="/users"
  component={NavLink}
  selected={isUserRoute}
>
  ...
</ListItemButton>
```

### Update

To use the `useMatch` hook for each `ListItemButton` I suggest factoring `ListItemButton` out into its own component.

Example:

```
const LinkButton = ({ children, to }) => {
  const selected = useMatch(to);

  return (
    <ListItemButton
      component={NavLink}
      to={to}
      selected={selected}
    >
      {children}
    </ListItemButton>
  );
};
```

Use the `LinkButton` instead of `ListItemButton` in the UI.

```
<div>
  {listItems.map((item) => (
    <LinkButton key={item.label} to={item.path}>
      {item.label}
    </LinkButton>
  ))}
</div>
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-the-current-pathname-correctly-in-react-router-v6]

If you prefer keeping the path matching localized to the parent component, import and use the `useLocation` hook and `matchPath` utility from `react-router-dom`.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();

...

<div>
  {listItems.map((item) => (
    <ListItemButton
      component={NavLink}
      to={item.path}
      selected={matchPath(item.path, pathname)}
    >
      {item.label}
    </ListItemButton>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm looks good! Let me try this out?

Comment: How to get the benefit of this when looping over an array to render a list (the side nav links)?

Comment: here's a full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-resonance-ivuvpr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: or for example, what if I had a code block that needs to check using the useMatch inside a useEffect? how can I use useMatch inside useEffect then?

Comment: @Normal Updated answer with example for matching several mapped paths. Included is a running fork from your codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese, Now I have a second place in my code that colors another block on the page based on the path. the way it works is inside useEffect. the way I mentioned it in the previous comment. How to use useMatch (or an alternative) inside the useEffect() hook? how to do the comparison inside the `useEffect()` hook? is it supported by React Router? or do I have to create my own comparison method *somehow*?

Comment: @Normal You can't call React hooks from nested callbacks, so `useMatch` won't work in the `useEffect` callback. You *could* import and call the `matchPath` utility that the `useMatch` hook uses under the hood.

Comment: The `matchPath` [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/router.ts#L382-L437) and to see how it's used/referenced, here is the `useMatch` [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L95-L118). It's pretty trivial, pass the pattern you want to match along with `location.pathname` to the `matchPath` function.

Comment: AMAZING, Thanks!!! you deserve the GOLDEN BUZZ   if you have time, modify the answer to make it use the `matchPath`, because I believe it's the way to go instead of the first solution (exporting the logic to multiple components (is it even possible?!)). Just for the future generations, if any kid in the future watched this.  `<ListItemButton key={item.text} to={item.path} component={NavLink} selected={matchPath(item.path, pathname)}>`

Comment: Who else thinks that the `useMatch()` hook is useless and must be deprecated? (just upvote, to respect the stackoverflow *strict* rules)

Comment: @Normal No problem. It's trivial enough to keep in the main component. I usually just prefer abstracting out data/logic like that, but that is entirely a personal preference.